# defining the integer value retrieved from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using data format as 1 for male, 2 for female and 3 for undefined GENDER in my database. How can I assign these values in my view i.e. for 1 show MALE , for 2 show FEMALE and for 3 show UNDEFINED? It is possible to do it from sql code but how can I do this from my view or controller?

Also I want to highlight the rows which have gender as undefined. How can I do this?

controller block

```
public ActionResult Display()
        {            
            return View(db.P_GET_USER().ToList());
        }
```

view block

```
@model IEnumerable<final.Models.P_GET_USER_Result>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Display";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Display</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.USERNAME)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NAME)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GENDER)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.STATUS)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CREATED_DATE)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.USERNAME)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAME)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GENDER)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.STATUS)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CREATED_DATE)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick dirty approach would be to put the conditional code in your view. Another way can be to add a helper method in your view to do that:

```
@helper GetGender(int gender)
{
   string genderText = "";
    switch (gender)
    {
      case 1:
        genderText = "Male";
        break;
      case 2:
        genderText = "Female";
      case 3:
        genderText = "Undefined";
        break;
      default;
        break;

     return genderText;
   }

}
```

and then use it like:

```
<td>
   @GetGender(item.Gender)
</td>
```

More better would be to move this at some common place and reuse it in each view where needed.

A more better than above would be to have a view model which returns the respected text based on the `Gender` property value in your view and the view would be strongly typed with that view model and will just display it.

Comment: Thank You for this answer. But please can you refer me some examples where this is done. I am new to MVC framework. How can I reuse the view?

Comment: where to place that helper in the view? I am getting error. Please can you keep the whole code of view keeping this helper block. Thank You!!!

Comment: @user4221591 this might help: https://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/functions-inside-page-using-razor-view-engine-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Using the code `return genderText;` getting error `Unreachable code detected`. Please help!!!